# Reaching kedusha during silent shemone esre

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, tzibur-community, kedusha-prayer

When the chazzan starts kedusha in chazarat hashatz while you're davening, are you supposed to answer the chant, continue in your tefilla, or just not say anything?

Comment: leon sada, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the important question! I look forward to seeing you around the site.

Answer (score 7):

> אינו פוסק לא לקדיש ולא לקדשה אלא ישתק
>   ויכון למה שאומר שליח-צבור ויהא כעונה
>   א"ח קד:ז

One who is still reciting the Shemoneh Esrei (i.e. has not **concluded** *Sim Shalom/Shalom Rav*) should not respond to the shliach tzibur but should pause and listen quietly (Shulchan Aruch [Orach Chaim 104:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.104.7?lang=bi)).

If one has concluded the Shemoneh Esrei proper but is still reciting the concluding tefillos customary to say during the silent Shemoneh Esrei see  [O.C. 122:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.122.1?lang=bi)

Comment: Interestingly, Rabbi Dr. Yosef Dov Soloveichik held that pausing and listening intently to the chazan would also be considered an interruption in your prayer (based on how he understood "shomeya k'oneh"), and thus it was best to just keep going with your own prayer.  But Yirmiyahu's answer (that of Shulchan Aruch!) is the normative one.

Comment: It's a machlokes Rashi & rabbeinu tam, but we hold like rashi.

Comment: I have heard but not read the opinion that you say kodash, baruch, and yimloch in your head with the tzibbur.

Comment: @Shalom If I'm not mistaken, his son-in-law R Lichtenstein makes a tnai that he should only be yotzei through shomeya k'oneh if the halacha is like the opinion that it's ok to do that.

Comment: @Shalom Now I've heard that his grandson R M Lichtenstein holds pausing is an interruption not because of shomea keoneh but because focusing one's attention elsewhere breaks the fundamental rule of tefila which is to be Omeid Lifnei Hamelech.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not *concluded* the bracha of Sim Shalom, i.e., said,

"בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה'. הַמְבָרֵךְ אֶת עַמּו יִשרָאֵל בַּשָּׁלום.
יִהְיוּ לְרָצון אִמְרֵי פִי וְהֶגְיון לִבִּי לְפָנֶיךָ. ה' צוּרִי וְגואֲלִי:"

just stand there quietly and listen to the chazzan.

Answer (score 2):

If you reach the end of Mechaye Meisim at the same time that the shaliach tzibbur begins kedusha, you answer kedusha (Shulchan aruch [O.C. 109:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.109.2?lang=bi))